# How to install free software with Software without registration?

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install Arduino IDE software through 'Software'-named software in ubuntu. It failed with message 'authentication was required'. I think Linux is free software. Why I need to register? Who collect that information and what purpose? Then I tried to register and it was successfull but this stupidly named 'Software'-software does not accept my password. Why? Why I need to register for free software? I have been used Ubuntu for years and not never before needed to register anywhere. How I can break that software registration so that I can again freely use Ubuntu?

And, why this forum forces to use tags on this post? And then it does not allow tags like 'install', 'software' or 'ubuntu-should-be-free'... First I tried to post question to ubuntu forum, but it was read only! What sense is that?

Comment: You do not need to register.  You do need to use your password when changing your system, like installing software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use the *Software Center* - neither do I.

You can either
install it via command line `sudo apt-get install arduino`
or - especially if you prefer a more up-to-date version, you can download it from
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to register. You do need to use your password when changing your system, like installing software.  The password you made when you installed Ubuntu, this is what the software store or sudo asks for.